# Selecting the limits to find flux through a hemisphere in polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates

I'm trying to evaluate the flux through hemisphere and reached this:
$$
\int_0^{0.5\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{I \cos(\phi)}{r^2} r^2 \sin(\theta) ~ d\phi d\theta \\
$$

The limits chosen above give the right values I needed after integration.

My question is, why can't I use the limits 0<ϕ<π and 0<θ<π ? Since that seems to give a zero when I try to integrate it, but when I try to visualize it as area swept it seems to give a hemisphere.

EDIT: I'm using the convention where θ is angle from azimuth

Comment: How did you get there.... traditionally, $\phi$ goes "north south" and for a hemisphere would range from $[0,\frac {\pi}{2}]$ and $\theta$ goes "east west" ranges from $[0, 2\pi)$

Comment: Sorry about that, should've made clear the convention my lecturer uses for polar coordinates is the opposite of yours